# MySql Update with count based on an input of comma separated values

Tags: mysql, sql

If I were to supply MySql a comma separated string like ('US,UK,CA') (which comes from a form through a php script), how can I get MySql to loop through that string and do a count for each country code in there and update a different table where the country codes in that table are equal to the country codes in the string.

Example:

**table_a**

```
"id"    "countries"
"1"     "US,CA"
"2"     "US,CA"
"3"     "US,AU"
"4"     "US,UK"
"5"     "US"
```

**table_b**

```
"id"    "country"   "total"
"1"     "US"        "0"
"2"     "CA"        "0"
"3"     "UK"        "0"
"4"     "AU"        "0"
```

How can I do:

**Eg: if I supplied ('US,UK,CA')**

```
update table_b set country = (

    select count(id) from table_a where country = (// each country in that string ('US,UK,CA'))

) where country = (country currently selected from the string above)
```

Can something like this be done? It works OK if there's just one country. How can I do it when there are more?

In the end, I'm hoping to end up with results like:

```
table_b
"id"    "country"   "total"
"1"     "US"        "5" // There are 5 in table_a
"2"     "CA"        "2" // There are 2 in table_a
"3"     "UK"        "1" // Only 1 in table_a
"4"     "AU"        "1" // Only 1 in table_a
```

Comment: you want update total in table b ?

Comment: @echo_Me Yes `table_b` as in the last example in my question.

Comment: Normalization's not an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that for the county 'CA':

```
 update table2 
 set total = (

select count(*) from table1 where FIND_IN_SET(country, countries)
)
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e57dc/1)

Or by one country

```
 update table2 
 set total = (

  select count(*) from table1 where FIND_IN_SET('CA', countries)
 )
  WHERE country = 'CA'
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a247a/1)

EDIT: i dont know what you exactly looking for , but if you need special countries .Just add a WHERE clause

```
   update table2 
 set total = (

 select count(*) from table1 where FIND_IN_SET(country, countries)
 )
 WHERE country IN ('US','UK','CA')
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a237d2/1)

Comment: @echo_me I need to put the entire string in there like ('US,UK,CA') as I've shown in my question, and not one at a time, or like what Ryx5 has done either.

Comment: Umm... I cant do : `update table2 
 set total = (

  select count(*) from table1 where FIND_IN_SET('US,UK,CA', countries)
 )` So that way all countries in that string will be updated?

Comment: Thanks. You're third solution looks like it's the one. But just one thing: If I were to specify 'US','CA' in the WHERE clause, would it do a count for all the countries including `UK` and `AU` which are in the table, or only for the countries I specify. I'm actually trying to avoid going through each and every country in the table.

Comment: only countries you specified , you didnt look demo ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54343/discussion-between-jmenezes-and-echo-me).